# SalesForce SOQL MALFORMED_QUERY

Tags: salesforce, soql

Why is this SOQL query returning `MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected token:` on

```
Select id FROM account 
where id = '0012000000I7MkRAAV' or id = '0012000000I7MkRAAV' 
and id = '0012000000I7MkRAAV'
```

Changing "and" to "or" returns the result just fine:

```
Select id FROM account 
where id = '0012000000I7MkRAAV' or id = '0012000000I7MkRAAV' 
or id = '0012000000I7MkRAAV'
```

I am executing the query in Force explorer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to group your and/or's so that its not ambiguous, e.g.

```
Select id FROM account where id = '0012000000I7MkRAAV' or (id = '0012000000I7MkRAAV' and id = '0012000000I7MkRAAV')
```

Comment: This works in deed, but I still do not get the point - why should I be forced to group values in WHERE clause. Issue of ambiguous fields is not resolved this way, you just need to reference values explicitly over data table name. Is there any official documentation regarding this? I have not managed to find any reference.

Comment: x or (Y and Z) is very different to (x or y) and Z

Comment: True, but I still can not see what it has to do with MALFORMED_QUERY. Brackets are only affecting logic of the WHERE clause. Anyway, I will use above solution as a workaround. Thanks for your help.

Comment: x or y and z is not allowed as its not clear which combination you mean, and so it returns an error.

Comment: Odd. I'm not doubting that superfell is right, but in most other languages **And** has precedence over **Or**. Good to know that SOQL requires the disambiguation.

Comment: I have accepted Superfell's answer, as it appears to be correct. Still, I would like to see if anyone can point to official docs about this.

Comment: Why are you using the same Id for the three cases? Is this just for the example? As stated above, if you use two different Id with the 'and' the SOQL won't return any value. Here's an official answer to the parenthesis requirement: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/NET-Development/Parenthesis-requirements-in-SOQL/td-p/9314

Comment: Its in the SOQL docs http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that one account record can't has two ids in the same time. One object record has just one Id. In this query you can use only OR statement

Comment: This does not help. This query also executes fine: Select id FROM account where id = '0012000000I7MkRAAV' and id = '0012000000I7MkRAAV' and id = '0012000000I7MkRAAV'. It has multiple "and". Even if you were right, "MALFORMED_QUERY" would not be returned as an error. It indicates syntax problem.

Comment: sorry, I not saw that you use the same Id in all cases. I guess that this behavior based on inner implementation of SOQL, anyway for getting result in this case just one Id is enough. What is the reason to use same id on this query?

Comment: The above query is simplified version. I just wanted to make sure that something else is not making an issue. I know that I do not need same Id multiple times, but it must not (or should not) cause MALFORMED_QUERY.